# Should I Put Critical Section While Getting Connection from OCCI Environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I'm writing a multi-threaded application. My worker threads get connection from an environment object as follows:.

```
//EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
conn = env->createConnection(username, password, connStr);
//LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
```

For concurrency, should the connection be created in a critical section or not? Does the env need it? And why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `createConnection` is thread-safe then you don't need it.

If `createConnection` isn't thread-safe then you do need the critical section.

Consult your documentation to see whether it's thread-safe or not.  If it doesn't explicitly  say it's thread-safe, them play it safe and wrap it in a critical section.

Edit:  Of course, all of the above assumes that multiple threads will be calling `createConnection`.  If they're not, then obviously you won't need the critical section at all.

Comment: It says it's thread safe if the environment is created in THREADED_MUTEXED mode. But still, after a while, the threads get locked while creating connection.

http://www.youngcow.net/doc/oracle10g/appdev.102/b14294/reference014.htm

Comment: My reading of those docs are that calls to `createEnvironment()` are thread-safe if `THREADED_MUTEXED` is used.  However, nothing is said about `createConnection` being thread-safe.  If you're experiencing problems and they go away when you wrap `createConnection` in a critical section, then you should leave the critical section in place.

Comment: I'm running the application with my critical sections in about 3 hours and no problem happened so far. However, I'm still in doubt because it is running much slower than that without critical sections. Also I guess it doesn't mean it's thread safe just because it doesn't get locked while testing. Am I right?